# Is there anyway to have an HTML variable like this?

Tags: html, variables

I am working in a webpage where client scripting is not allowed. This webpage uses a very huge  verbose tag in the shape of:

```
<embed src="X" flashvars="Y"/>
```

It is part of a tmeplate, so it will be used in lots of pages, so I have to change the hardcoded params in an easy way for all them.

I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this in HTML:

```
<var name="X" content="foo">
<var name="Y" content ="bar">

<embed src="<X/>" flashvars="<Y/>"/>
```

So the last part would not be changed in template and all child inherited pages

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML alone cannot do this. HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. It doesn't even have variables.

You need server-side coding for this. PHP is the most popular, though there are numerous others available. Then you could do this:

```php
<?php
    $x = 'something';
    $y = 'somethingElse';
?>
<embed src="<?php echo $x; ?>" flashvars="<?php echo $y; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. HTML is static.

If you cannot use a clientside script have you thought about a serverside script?

Answer (score 1):

Not through HTML directly.

You could use JavaScript to inject the values, but HTML itself does not store variables.

Comment: JavaScript is client-side programming and not available.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit of the post. Can't think of a situation that would disallow JavaScript, though.

Comment: There is, when site is not yours... :)

Comment: @LiamMcSherry Some offices/organisations disable Javascript because it is deemed a potential security risk. You can't assume that Javascript is always available.

Comment: @LiamMcSherry Corporation which don't allow javascript, sites for screenreaders etc